# Retirar caracteres \ de String

Tags: php, string

Tenho esse campo abaixo que retorna da minha API, porém como podem observar ele está com `\n`, `\r` e `\` entre :`na categoria \"A ou B\"` eu gostaria de removê-los:

```
 `"observacao":` `"Conforme Resolução CONTRAN 561/2015.\nÉ Obrigatório relatar a situação observada. \nEx: \"Condutor habilitado na categoria \"A ou B\" conduzindo CVC (Combinação de Veículos de Carga)\".Pode Configurar Crime (Art.309-CTB).\n\nPPD=Permissão Provisória para Dirigir.\nAlterado pela Lei Federal 13.281/2016\n\n\nAlterado pela Lei Federal 13.281/2016\n"`
```

Ao passar um str_replace e o preg_replace dessa forma:

```
$frasesRetiradas = array('Conforme Resolução CONTRAN561/2015.', 'É Obrigatório relatar a situação observada.');
$response['Infracao']['observacao'] = str_replace($frasesRetiradas,'', $response['Infracao']['observacao']);
$response['Infracao']['observacao'] = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', trim($response['Infracao']['observacao']));
```

Ele me retornou assim:

```
    `"observacao":` `"Conforme Resolução CONTRAN 561/2015. Ex: \"Condutor habilitado na categoria \"A ou B\" conduzindo CVC (Combinação de Veículos de Carga)\".Pode Configurar Crime (Art.309-CTB).PPD=Permissão Provisória para Dirigir.Alterado pela Lei Federal 13.281/2016Alterado pela Lei Federal 13.281/2016"`
```

Ou seja, retirou os `\n` porém manteve o `\` na string. Como faço para
remover esse `\`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para especificar uma contrabarra literal, dobre-a (\\). Todas as outras ocorrências da contrabarra serão tratadas como uma contrabarra literal: isso significa que outras sequências de escape que se esteja acostumado a utilizar, como \r ou \n, serão literalmente impressas em vez de ter qualquer significado especial.

Extrato do manual do PHP disponível em: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php

```
$frasesRetiradas = array('Conforme Resolução CONTRAN561/2015.', 'É Obrigatório relatar a situação observada.');
$response['Infracao']['observacao'] = str_replace($frasesRetiradas,'', $response['Infracao']['observacao']);
$response['Infracao']['observacao'] = preg_replace('~[\\r\\n]+~', '', trim($response['Infracao']['observacao']));
```

Comment: Vale notar que seria muito melhor ele usar str_replace que não teria nada desses problemas, além de mais eficiente.

Comment: Verdade mesmo, mais simples e prático!

Comment: Eu fiz dessa forma porem ele me retorna as \ na string :
"Conforme Resolução CONTRAN 561/2015. Ex: \"Condutor habilitado na categoria \"A ou B\" conduzindo CVC (Combinação de Veículos de Carga)\".Pode Configurar Crime (Art.309-CTB).PPD=Permissão Provisória para Dirigir.Alterado pela Lei Federal 13.281/2016Alterado pela Lei Federal 13.281/2016"

Comment: @VictorPadovan Se vc está retornando um JSON, então `\"` é uma sequência de escape válida para que as aspas não sejam confundidas com os delimitadores da string (ou seja, `"abc"` é uma string que só tem os caracteres `abc`, mas se eu quiser que tenha aspas dentro dela, eu teria que colocar `"\"abc\""`, para que ela seja `"abc"`). Então vc não deveria tirar o ``\``

Comment: @hkotsubo Hmmmmm, etendi, muito obrigado

Comment: @VictorPadovan Vale lembrar que na regex não faz diferença trocar `\r` por `\\r`, ainda mais estando entre aspas simples: https://ideone.com/YOrDGR